# Generate 33 bytes public key for curve25519 in python

Tags: private-key, public-key, spongycastle, python-cryptography, pynacl

Using Java's spongycastle, i am able to generate `curve25519` private keys(32 bytes) and public keys(33 bytes).

Similarly for Python, i am using `Nacl` library for `curve25519` but here public key generated is of 32 bytes only. The one byte of y co-ordinate is missing in public key.

```
from nacl.public import PrivateKey
import binascii

privKey = PrivateKey.generate()
pubKey = privKey.public_key

print("privKey:", binascii.hexlify(bytes(privKey)))
print("pubKey: ", binascii.hexlify(bytes(pubKey)))
```

any suggestion why `Nacl` library is not compressing the public key ?

Answer (score 0):

spongycastle(Java) and  PyNacl(Python) are totally two different libraries.

PyNacl(Python) and LazySodiumJava(Java) derive from C library libsodium, they can only generate 32bit key.

I think maybe you could look for other Python packages, which is consistent with spongycastle(Java).